# How to simplify borders between polygons in shapely?

Tags: python, geoprocessing, shapely

I have some fairly complex, and not completely accurate shapes stored as shapely `Polygon` objects. I'm trying to find the common borders, which should be as easy as finding the `LineString` returned from `poly1.intersection(poly2)`.

However, due the the slight inaccuracies I'm finding that `intersection` is returning `Polygon` and `Point` objects, or sometimes a `GeometryCollection` object. Never a simple `LineString` except in my simple test code where the `Polygon` shapes are accurate.

Is there any way of simplifying the borders, like a "snap-to" method, or a tolerance parameter that might ease my pain?

Answer (score 2):

Since version 1.5, shapely provides a [snap](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html#snapping) function that can be used in that way.

From the shapely documentation

```
from shapely.ops import snap
square = Polygon([(1,1), (2, 1), (2, 2), (1, 2), (1, 1)])
line = LineString([(0,0), (0.8, 0.8), (1.8, 0.95), (2.6, 0.5)])
result = snap(line, square, 0.5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Although not a complete answer, I think I have an algorithm that could work.

1. For each point in `poly1`, if the `Point` is closer than `epsilon` to a `LineString` in `poly2` then move the `Point` onto the `LineString`.
2. For each pair of `Point` objects (one from `poly1` and one from `poly2`) if the two are closer than `epsilon` then move both to the central point between them.
3. For any sets of adjacent collinear `Point` objects on the same `Polygon`, remove all but the `Point` at each end.

Answer (score 0):

If you are dealing with [conterminous](https://www.google.com/search?q=conterminous) polygons, you probably want to use [TopoJSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14740705/difference-between-geojson-and-topojson) to represent your data, as it by definition stores shared boundaries in a common structure, making them *identical*.  Data file size should be reduced, as well.

That said, as cool as it is, I don't think the format is widely used, and you still have the problem of how to get your data in to that format.  If @francisopuga's "snap" answer works, then maybe use TopoJSON after that.